# Lightning Experience: Setting default value of "Record Owner" of Convert Lead page

Tags: lightning-experience, leads, lead-conversion, user-interface

When the Convert Lead page loads, I would like to have the Record Owner field emptied out or the current user's name filled in by default. How can I do this?

I have read these solutions:

- https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000CmlXAAS
- https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000E5bRQAS
- https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000ZnJzQAK

, but all of them involved in calling the Classic Convert Lead page, like creating custom buttons/links or VisualForce page redirecting users to the Classic Convert Lead page.

Is there any way to do this in Lightning Experience, or am I limited to those solutions?

Thanks in advance!

ps. Custom Buttons don't show up in Lightning Experience.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom button to redirect to a custom lightning app and in apex use database.convertlead

If your only intention to set the owner on the conversion then

1. Hide the standard owner field from the UI
2. Create a formula field which shows current user and show that on the
   UI.
3. User process builder or workflow to populate owner

hope this will cover your requirement.

Comment: Custom lightning app? Do I need to build up a new Convert Lead UI with Lightning App Builder, and then write apex codes? I'm new to SalesForce. Thanks.

Comment: If your only intention to set the owner on the conversion then hide the field from the UI, Create a formula field which shows current user and show that on the UI

Comment: How do I hide the owner field on Convert Lead page? Where should I start?

Comment: Except for custom app, I don't think there is a way to achieve this in LEX.